# Namespace 'Interop' does not exist in namespace "Microsoft.Office"

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, ms-office

I have included Microsoft Office 2013 components reference in my project but still it is showing

> "interop does not exist in Microsoft.Office namespace".

Comment: What exactly references did you include to the project? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library

Answer (score 3):

According to your question you have missing Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library.
Go to references and add reference "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" or "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" it will resolve your error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set '**Embed Interop Types**' to True?
[image: EmbedInteropTypes]

Comment: being a beginner i am not well versed with visual studio. Please help me open this dialogue box that you have displayed above. Thank you in advance

Comment: @SayliKaranjkar You can see that Properties window by double-clicking the referenced libraries. (it is in the solution explorer -> Reference)

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old but seems like the most likely to show up in a search given the original title.

This happened to me today out of the blue in a system that has been using interop.excel for almost 10 years.

After some hair pulling - the answer turned out to be that lowercase "interop" produces the error while upper case I ( "Interop" ) resolves it.

Further, I have not changed that "using" statement in at least 5 years, go figure.